# Save tmux status is possible?

Tags: tmux

Is it possible, in tmux, to "export" current session status? A list of windows and panes opened and/or something like that. Or, .. is possible to store session somewhere, and re-open it next time tmux will be opened?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) over on GitHub. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it contains informations I need. I'll study asap. I have an home made bash script, configurable, ... but make new configuration is slow process. Maybe with the help of continuum I can change some my behavior ... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin that enables *manual* saving and restoring of tmux sessions.

[tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) is a separate plugin built on top of `tmux-resurrect` and enables auto-saving of tmux sessions (every 15 minutes by default). There is also the optional setting to restore last saved session when tmux is started.

I recommend setting up and playing with `tmux-resurrect` first.

Comment: Also this is a very nice help.